# Why is the area to the right of a DIV clickable?

Tags: css, html, area, clickable

I have a clickable div, but the area to the right of the div is also clickable. I don't want that. How can I fix that?

Comment: Post your html and css, how do you expect us to help you without even seeing the code?

Comment: You are definitely right Matteo Mosca, I somehow forgot to even post the code. But the problem was solved using display:inline-block like like RedX suggested.

Comment: @Student: Then it was always the area of the div and not to the right of ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your div is `display: block` as it is the default. Try `display: inline-block`.